# how to create column in mysql table at runtime

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

In my web application I have a form in that I am creating dynamic select boxes and text boxes as per need(It can be more than 1), default there is one pair of select box and text box and my table has two columns for storing values of that select box and text box and values are getting store in my table , but problem is if I add more than one pair of select And text box in my form how to store values in my table? Could it be possible to create columns in table at RUN TIME as per need.

Comment: creating new columns in a table at runtime based on user interaction is not suggested. It is not a good approach in my opinion

Comment: You are probably better rethinking the existing schema than adding fields at runtime.

Comment: I suggest you create one more column as ID and for each newly created textBox associate an unique number and save a row with that ID and the data in the data column. (Its just an idea since I don't know what is the actual design .. )

Answer (score 0):

If you can count the number of text boxes and select boxes you can use sql's alter table query at runtime to add columns dynamically.

Comment: How? can you specify sample query if I have 3 pair of select and text boxes.

Comment: the table holding some amount of data and if we alter it's structure at runtime will data in that table would remain as it is?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create by using the good old JDBC; you can see [an example here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-tables.htm). As suggested by others, this is not a proper design approach.

I do not know if it is possible by using JPA since the table creation is a property that you need to specify in persistence.xml . JPA can automatically create tables, but you will lose all data each time you want persist data to an existing table (unless there is some override configuration parameter which is unknown to me).

Answer (score 0):

You created a bad schema for your application.
To simply solve this try schema like this:

```
groupid, selectbox, textbox
```

and store the data in more rows.

For example if there is 2 pairs of boxes then you store two rows:

```
1, 'select', 'text'
1, 'select2', 'text2'
```

And so on.